# Adding an array of user id's to a model - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, select, associations

I'm trying to make an app for students to post projects. When they create a post, they can add their team mates. Each student has a user id, and I want the student creating the project to be able to select other ids from the same organisation as their team mates.  The model associations are:

user

```
has_and belongs_to_many :projects
```

project

```
has_and belongs_to_many :users
```

I have a project model, with:

```
:user_id (integer)
:team_mates (integer)
```

In my projects form, I want the student (creating the project, to select other ids (from a list of students who belong to the same organisation) as team mates. My first question is whether the team mates attribute should be an integer (since there might be more than one team mate, in which case, can this attribute hold an array?

My next problem is - I'm lost for how to go about this. If I add a select line to my project form, to add user_ids, where the user.organisation equals the current user's id, then the student creating the project should be able to see a list of possible options.

Then in my projects show page, I want to display each student in the team.

Can anyone help with how to approach this? I'm lost and stuck for where to find examples of similar problems.

UPDATE

I found this article: http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/07/30/bi-directional-and-self-referential-associations-in-rails/

I'm confused though. I don't know whether I should join projects with users (through a join table I've called teams) or whether I should join users with users, through a join table called 'teams'.

If I join users with projects, it makes sense to me that the user who creates a project can choose other users to be project team mates. However, it isn't true to say that each project has many teams (which is what this example shows). I'm not sure about changing the has_many to a has_one, since the article goes on to explain about the has_many through join.

If i join users to users, then a user with many projects may have different teams for each project. So that wouldn't be correct.

Taking the article as an example, I tried:

create teams model:

```
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|

      t.references :project, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :team_mate, index: true


      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :teams, :projects, column: :team_mate_id
    add_index :teams, [:project_id, :team_mate_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Team.rb

```
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :team_mate, class_name: "Profile"
```

Teams controller (I will figure this out later - its commented for now since I don't have a matchmaker section yet):

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController

before_action :resync_matches, only: :index

def index
  # several orders of magnitude faster
  @team_mates = current_user.team_mates
                               .page(params[:page])
end

private

def resync_matches
  # only resync if we have to
  if current_user.teams_outdated?
    new_matches = MatchMaker.matches_for(current_user)
    current_user.team_mates.replace(new_matches)
  end
end

end
```

project.rb

```
has_one :team
has_many :team_mates, through: :teams, dependent: :destroy
```

I changed this so that projects have one team rather than many.

Im confused about this and not sure how to get this up and running. In my projects form, I want to offer users (who create projects) to pick profiles of other users who are team mates. I'm lost at this point.

I tried to make a Teams Helper:

```
module TeamsHelper
  def team_mate_options
    s = ''
    Profile.in_same_organisation.each do |profile|
      s << "<option value='#{profile.id}'>#{profile.user.full_name}</option>"
    end
    s.html_safe
  end



end
```

In my profile.rb, I tried to make a scope to get the profiles who belong to the same organisation as the project creator (although I'm not sure this is correct):

```
scope :in_same_organisation, -> (organisation_id) { where(organisation_id: organisation_id) }
```

Then in my projects form I tried to add a select option:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <%= label_tag 'team_mates', 'Choose team mates' %>
                        <%= select_tag 'team_mates', team_mate_options, multiple: true, class: 'form-control chosen-it' %>
                    </div>
```

VISHAL'S SUGGESTION

Taking Vishal's suggestion, I have implemented the structure proposed. I'm having a problem with the projects form. My complete setup is:

**Models**
Organisation

```
has_many :profiles
```

Profile

```
  has_many :projects
  belongs_to :organisation
  has_many :teams, foreign_key: "team_mate_id"
  has_many :team_projects, through: :teams, source: :project
```

Project

```
belongs_to :profile
has_many :teams
has_many :team_mates, through: :teams
```

Team

```
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :team_mate, class_name: "Profile"
```

My teams table has:

```
create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.integer  "team_mate_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
```

Then in my project form, I have:

```
<%= f.label :team_mates, :label => "Add a team member" %>
<%= f.collection_select(:team_mate_id, Profile.all, :id, :team_mate_select, {prompt: "Select the team member"}, {:required => true}) %>
```

In my profile model, I have:

```
def team_mate_select
    self.user.formal_name
end
```

My structure is that profiles belong to users. In user, I have  method called formal name which adds a title to the users name.

When I save this and try it, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `team_mate_id' for #<Project:0x007fa08ed3d8e0>
```

(highlighting the collection select line of the project form)

My projects/form.html.erb has:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>

                <div class="form-inputs">

                    <%= f.input :title, :label => "Title", autofocus: true %>
                    <%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :label => "Describe your project", :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>
                    <%= f.input :remark, :as => :text, :label => "Is there an interesting fact or statistic that's relevant to this research?", :input_html => {:rows => 5}, :placeholder => "In fact, ...(insert a fact which shows why this research might be interesting or relevant)" %>

                    <%= f.input :hero_image, :label => "Add an image" %>

                        <%= f.label :team_mates, :label => "Add a team member" %>
                        <%= f.collection_select(:team_id, Profile.all, :id, :team_mate_select, {prompt: "Select the team member"}, {:required => true}) %>


                <div class="form-actions" style="margin-top:50px">
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Create", :class => 'formsubmit' %>
                </div>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a `Team` model, with `has_and belongs_to_many` relations between a `User`model and a `team` model. Then, a `Team` represents an array of `User` objects.

Comment: Wouldn't it be between project and team? What would the attributes on that model be and how would I get them to work in my project model?

Comment: yes, additionally there would be a relation between `project` and `team`. If there is exactly one `team` for each `project`, then you just add a column `team_id` to your `project` model, plus a `belongs_to` relation. The relation between `user` and `team` is analogous to the relation between `user` and `project` that you already have. Aha, maybe your `projects` behave like `teams` in this respect? Then you would not need the `team` model at all.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Is your conclusion that a team model is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [self-referential associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association). You would have to create a join table that keeps the records of which user is team member of which user; something like following:

```
+-----------+----------------+------------+-------------+
|  user_id  | team_member_id | created_at | updated_at  |
+-----------|----------------+------------+-------------+
|           |                |            |             |
+-----------+----------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: So you think I need a new table for team members as well as a join table, instead of an attribute on the project model (for team mates)?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Because a single user can have multiple team mates.

Comment: But how do i add that to a project? Different projects can have different team mates

Answer (score 0):

You can think on the lines of 'what resource you are creating'. When you add a new project, you are creating a Project resource. When the project's creator adds someone else to the project, you are creating a ProjectMemberRelationship resource. So, I think you can get what you need with only these models - Organisation, User, Project, ProjectMemberRelationship (and a table for each of them).

You will need a projects table that has a reference to users through user_id field.

Create ProjectMemberRelationship model with

```
rails generate model ProjectMemberRelationship project_id:integer member_id:integer
```

Organisation Model:

```
has_many :users
```

User model:

```
belongs_to :organization
has_many :projects
has_many :project_member_relationships, foreign_key: "member_id"
has_many: collaborated_projects, through: :project_member_relationships, source: :project
```

You need `foreign_key: "member_id"` as the column name is not user_id as expected by Rails by default. And you need `source: :project` because the column name is not collaborated_project_id but project_id.

Project model:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :project_member_relationships
has_many :members, through: :project_member_relationships
```

ProjectMemberRelationship model:

```
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :member, class_name: "User"
```

With models defined as above, every time a member is added to a project, a new row is added to project_member_relationships table that stores the project_id for the project and member_id of the user that was added, while users & projects tables are unaffected by this action.

Let's divide the task in 2 stops.

Step 1: A user creates a project.

Step 2: The user adds collaborators to the project.

Step 1 is fairly easy and straightforward. You create a project with, say its topic and user_id of the user who created it.

Now on the project's show page, you can have a form to add a new project_member_relationship. You only need 2 fields to submit here - member_id (for the user to be added) & project_id (which equals params[:id] on projects#show page). For member_id field, you can use collection_select where your collection is the users that belong to the same organisation as the creator, as required. Mind you, one submission of this form creates only one project member at a time.

I haven't tested the code yet but I'll be happy to help if you run into  issues.

Comment: Hi Vishal. Thank you so much for this help. I see what you're suggesting here and I think it makes sense.

Comment: Hope it works for you and gets you the intended result. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry Vishal, comment timer ran out..

I see you've followed the logical approach from the example I linked to originally about bi-directional associations, where the two objects being joined are linked through a join model and the objects have many such joins.

I'm wondering if it might make sense to design the relationships so that:
- A Project owns an instance of a model called 'Team'
- A Team has relationships to many profiles
- Each Project has exactly one Team and each Team has exactly one Project

Comment: So this would be different to the solution above where each project has many project_member_relationships and each project_member_relationships is a one-to-ones mapping of project to profile.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is some programming / data structuring convention to approach it in the first way? I imagine there might be some future benefits if doing more complex queries across these relationships if so. Do you think one way is preferable from the other technically?

Comment: I think, it boils down to your requirement. Are there any specific attributes that a team would have? If no, then you need to think if an extra model (and a database table) for team is needed. If you introduce the Team model, you will also need to introduce one more model that associates a team with a user - with fields team_id & user_id - which serves the purpose the ProjectMemberRelationship model in the answer does.

Comment: In the latter case, if you query for, say users of a particular project, you will  need to follow this path - project -> team -> team_user_relationships -> users. Whereas without the Team model, you will do this - project -> project-member-relationships -> users. Notice the extra 'team' layer.. So I'd add the extra model only if I'm sure of its utility. Having said that, it's just 'my' way of thinking and I'm still new to Rails myself.

Comment: If you need something like `project1 = Project.find(1)` and then `project1.team` to get a collection of the project's members, you can always define a function/method in Project model that would return that collection/team for you.

Comment: Hi Vishal, I added my attempt to try your suggestion above. Can you see what I've done wrong?

Comment: Sure. Can you post the complete form? That would help in figuring it out.

Comment: It looks like you're calling team_mate_id on 'project' when in fact it's a 'team' attribute.

Comment: But isn't instead of 'member' in your example. If I change team_mate_id, to team_id, i get the same kind of error: undefined method 'team_id'

Comment: I still get the error if I change it to:  has_one :team
    has_many :team_mates, through: :team

Comment: Can you post the complete form please?